# How do you change a value in an object that has a long lifetime in Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac

An existing application is based on MVVM Light and uses an autofac container to create objects. During the lifetime of the application, an already created objects needs to be rebuild with new parameters. I'm less experienced with autofac

Example:

```
 containerBuilder.RegisterType<SerialPortController>().Named<ISerialPortController>("ConveyorController").WithParameter(
            new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string) && pi.Name == "portName",
                (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<ISettingsModel>().ConveyorSerialPort)).SingleInstance();
```

For example, "portName" is changed. 
I don't see a good solution for this. Anyone experience with it?

Comment: portName is the name of the parameter, how can it change during the object lifetime?

Comment: @tomsky I suspect OP meant the resolved parameter value (i.e. `ctx.Resolve<ISettingsModel>().ConveyorSerialPort`)

Comment: Yes. you are right. I mean the value of the parameter :)

Answer (score 2):

From your snippet, you have:

- An `ISerialPortController` implementation called `SerialPortController` that is registered with the application as a *single instance*. This means it will live for the life of the Autofac container, which is also usually the life of the application.
- A value that the `SerialPortController` uses which comes from an `ISettingsModel`. The settings within that model may change over the course of the application and when they do the `SerialPortController` needs to start using the new value.

I'll start off by answering the simple question: **There is no way to reinitialize a singleton in Autofac.** The benefits and drawbacks of a singleton are that... it's a singleton. Once it's built, it's built. You have to drop the whole container and rebuild it to get the singleton to rebuild.

**There are other ways to solve the problem** though that don't involve actually having to reinitialize the singleton.

## Option 1: Don't Make the Controller Singleton

Instead of making the controller a singleton, make it `InstancePerDependency`. The setting it consumes will only be held as long as the individual instance is alive.

There may be reasons you want it to be a singleton, like maybe it's expensive to create or maybe it acts as a resource pool or something. That's cool, there are more options. This is just the simplest answer.

## Option 2: Change the Port Parameter to Something More Dynamic

What I mean by that is, instead of having the `SerialPortController` take a literal port number, have it take a *function* that is used to retrieve the port number.

For example, let's say the `ISettingsModel` automatically always has the latest value. If you ask a singleton `ISettingsModel` for the `ConveyorSerialPort` it's *always* the latest. You could change the controller to take an `ISettingsModel` instead.

```cs
public class SerialPortController
{
  private readonly ISettingsModel _model;
  public SerialPortController(ISettingsModel model)
  {
    this._model = model;
  }
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // port will always be up to date.
    var port = this._model.ConveyorSerialPort;
    this.CommunicateOn(port);
  }
}
```

In this case, it's up to the `ISettingsModel` to keep its values fresh, but as long as that happens, the controller can be a singleton (and, ideally, so can `ISettingsModel` or else you'll have a [captive dependency situation](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html).

But let's say `ISettingsModel` is generated every time it's resolved. In order to get fresh settings, you have to get a new `ISettingsModel`. That's OK, you can do that with Autofac, too, using `Func<T>`:

```cs
public class SerialPortController
{
  private readonly Func<ISettingsModel> _modelFactory;
  public SerialPortController(Func<ISettingsModel> modelFactory)
  {
    this._modelFactory = modelFactory;
  }
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // port will always be up to date.
    var port = this._modelFactory().ConveyorSerialPort;
    this.CommunicateOn(port);
  }
}
```

The automatically generated `Func<ISettingsModel>` will resole a brand new `ISettingsModel` from the container. Since your controller is a singleton, it will come from the root of the container. **Be careful if `ISettingsModel` is disposable.** If it's disposable (`IDisposable`) then Autofac will hold on to it until the container is disposed, causing a memory leak. [There are ways to work around this, too.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html) but that can start getting kinda complicated and I want to get you a usable answer. The documentation is pretty good (if I do say so myself) and has lots of examples. It is long, but worth spending time checking out.

Comment: For great answers like yours, I wish stackoverflow will add a +100 upvote button

Comment: @Twan if you like it, please accept it as the answer so I get credit. Thanks!

Comment: Great explanation. Plus 1!

Comment: Thanks. If @Twan could come back and accept my answer, that'd be really helpful from that credit standpoint.